# Sprite Kit - Set position not doing anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to reset the ball after it hit the goal to the middle of the screen, but it seems I can no longer set it's position anymore after i declare it's position during declaration.

This is how i define my ball:

```
-(void)setUpBall {
    self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball"];
    self.ball.name = bName;
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);

    self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.ball.frame.size.width/2];
    self.ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
    self.ball.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    self.ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    self.ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    self.ball.physicsBody.dynamic = true;
    self.ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
    self.ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
    self.ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bCategory;
    self.ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pCategory | borderCategory;
    self.ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = borderCategory;
    [self addChild:self.ball];

    [self.ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(15, 10)];
}
```

This is my code to reset the ball to middle of the screen

```
-(void)reset {
    NSLog(@"reset method ran");
    [self.ball setPosition: CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];
}
```

It seems that the `reset` method is definitely ran since there was output from the `NSLog(@"reset method ran");` but the ball always continue moving like the `setPosition` never work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yopu could simply set up the ball again.

```
-(void)reset 
{
    NSLog(@"reset method ran");
    [self.ball removeFromParent];
    [self setUpBall];
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But do you have any idea why my above method does not work at all?

Comment: What is the status of the ball when you call the reset code, has it been removed from it's parent by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Doing things like setting position might not work in Sprite Kit if it's a result of a call from testing collisions or other things. You may need to add a BOOL property to your ball to flag it if you need to reset it, and then call the reset when you are updating all your sprites.

I have an asteroids type game where I was trying to replace one large asteroid with 3 smaller rocks when the collision detection against a player's missile fired – it did not work because the position was being set during the collision check part of the Sprite Kit update loop. When I added the new rocks during the standard part of the update loop, it worked fine.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but the terminology could be improved: a simulation cycle includes callbacks to update(), didUpdatePhysics() and didFinishUpdate().  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html  It might be that SpriteKit overwrote your changes, for example, while applying constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not replace your reset method with:

```
-(void)reset {
    NSLog(@"reset method ran");
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];
}
```

I tend to use this and not the `setPosition` method to relocate a sprite.

Comment: [self.ball setPosition: CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)]; is the same as self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];

Comment: When you use ball.position, it implicitly calls [ball setPosition:position];